# How to best method create multi theme in yii2?

Tags: yii2

In my project I need to organize multitemnost.
But it does not fit just different CSS files, my theme should be completely independent of each other.

All that comes to my mind is

my db:

user

```
-id
-other_colums*
```

themes:

```
-id
-other_colums
```

current_theme:

```
-id
-user_id
-theme_id
```

View code:

```
$param = get value from current_theme;

return $ this-> render ("{$param}-viewname");
```

so I have bad multi theme system.
How better make it in Yii2 ?

Comment: Do you need different themes per user?

Comment: Best way to manage css files is using Assets and Asset Bundles
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

Comment: If you need different themes per website, then best way is to use Advanced Project Template.
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md

Answer (score 0):

If use simple themes without active forms and widgets is simple:

- for each theme create asset bundle
- for each view create own view view/{theme}_index

Real integration is complicate. For each theme:

- create asset bundles for each functionality (forms, tables, wizards)
- create extended widgets for theme
- extend ActiveFileds - complicated
- create layouts
- create views (optional)
- ...

Example: https://github.com/mithun12000/adminUI